# Clarification on sorting-networks-size upper and lower bound

Tags: algorithm, sorting, sorting-network

Referring to this Wikipedia's article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network , with focus on the paragraph **Constructing sorting networks**.

Can you please explain what `Size, upper bound` and `Size, lower bound` (in the table) are?
I would expect that `lower bound` refers to the minimum connections needed to correctly sort an input of n numbers (am I correct?). If so, why bother with an `upper bound`? In theory, one could use a number of connections larger than the `upper bound` so how can it be established?
I have read the linked paper as well (ref. 11) but I am still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraphs after the table give a hint about the meaning of upper bound and lower bound:

> For one to ten inputs, minimal (*i.e.* size-optimal) sorting networks are known, and for higher values, lower bounds on their sizes *S(n)* can be derived inductively using a lemma due to Van Voorhis: *S(n + 1) ≥ S(n) + ⌈log2(n)⌉*.

The « upper bound » in the table apparently corresponds to size of the most size-optimal sorting network *currently known* for a given number of elements to sort. The known size-optimal sorting networks for 1 to 10 elements have been proven to be optimal, but we're not sure that the known size-optimal sorting networks for more elements are actually the most optimal ones. The « lower bound » corresponds to the theorical minimal size of a sorting network to sort a given number of elements: it may be possible that a sorting network of this size does not exists, but we haven't proven that yet.

To sum up:

- « Upper bound » represents the most size-optimal sorting network that has been found.
- « Lower bound » represents the theorical minimal size of a network. It has not been proven that such a network does not exist, but we haven't found any viable network of this size either.

---

As a side note I maintain [a library](https://github.com/Morwenn/cpp-sort) with size-optimal sorting networks, and their sizes correspond to the « upper bound » from the table (see also [the documentation](https://github.com/Morwenn/cpp-sort/wiki/Fixed-size-sorters#sorting_network_sorter) and [the implementation](https://github.com/Morwenn/cpp-sort/tree/master/include/cpp-sort/detail/sorting_network)).

Comment: Thanks! Very clear. Can you please link me 'a library with size-optimal sorting networks' I am very interested in having a look to that.

Comment: @alec_djinn No problem. I updated my answer to add link to the C++ library, and to specific places of the implementation and of the documentation. To be honest, due to how sorting networks work, the implementation is pretty uninteresting, but here it is :)